# sortDescriptorWithKey for generic NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

I have an NSManagedObject Book with a to-many relationship to an NSManagedObject `Title`, which has an NSString property `titleName`.

The `Title` object is not subclassed. It’s just a generic NSManagedObject. So you cannot access the `titleName` property simply by calling `title.titleName;` you must call `[title valueForKey:@“titleName”];`

I would think that an NSSortDescriptor with a key would in fact call `valueForKey` when accessing that key, but apparently not; the following code generates an “unrecognized selector” exception:

```
// Verify that “titles” have a property “titleName” that is an NSString.
for (NSManagedObject *title in self.book.titles)
    logIt(@"\ntitle name: %@.", [title valueForKey:@"titleName"]); // prints strings as expected, proving that “titleName” really is an NSString
// Set up the sort descriptor on “titleName” property and use it.
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"titleName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare)];
NSArray *arrayOfTitles = [self.book.titles sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Here’s what prints upon crash: *-[NSCFString localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare]: unrecognized selector sent to instance…*

It looks like NSSortDescriptor has failed to dig down to the string property, so it’s attempting to call `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` on some unidentified non-string object. Does that sound right? If so, is there any way around the problem using NSSortDescriptor, or do I have to run a custom comparator block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the trailing colon `:`, which is part of the selector:

```
@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)
```

It is correct that `sortDescriptorWithKey` uses Key-Value coding to access the properties.

Comment: Oh blast, I'm always making mountains out of molehills by missing something obvious like this. I really should delete this question, as it's merely a waste of space -- but I don't want to deprive you of the reputation points. Thanks for taking the time to set me straight!

Comment: @Wienke: You can delete it if you want, I have no problem with that.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out SO won't let me delete it since it has an answer. Well, maybe somebody else will make the same mistake and this will help. Sorry!